# Is it possible to make an android app through android studio using html 5 code?

Tags: android, html, material-design

I have made a website using HTML5.

However, I'm trying to make the app using the CSS, JavaScript and HTML I used for the website. Is that somehow possible?

**I must use Android Studio.**

Comment: you can use web view

Comment: yeah, make the website responsive, add the mobile version and show it in your app through a webview. not the best practice but a lot of webapp are made like this..

Comment: You don't even need an app... Just `save a link` to your site onto the home screen. And distribute the link.

Comment: Try using cordova

Comment: Well, I have to make an app using android studio. I have been given a HTML 5 stuff, need to implement into app.

Answer (score -2):

Nope, you can't do that.
Android Studio is based on Java (logic) and XML (design).

XML and CSS are a little bit similar. You have paddings and margins too.
However. Prepare yourself to put work into the project.

But why do you need an app when you can also show the same contents in a website that works on way more devices? You can also use a WebView to show your website in the app.

If it must be native and you can't use a WebView, just rebuilt the design, Check out the material design guidelines, stick to them and your app will be easy to use for the users and look awesome.

Links:
https://material.google.com/ (read through the components stuff)
https://design.google.com/icons/ (all icons)